# ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Tags: python, selenium

I have this code to fill a form

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome('driverchrome//chromedriver.exe')

#Open the form

driver.get('https://forms.gle/A3qCjSCXi5H64qA26')

#Add nombre
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys('hernan')

#Add apellido
driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys('caceres')

#Add nacionaldad
driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys('canada')


#Add rubro
driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys('pesca')


#for alternatives:
sexo_dict={'hombre': '//*[@id="i21"]/div[3]/div',
           'Mujer': '//*[@id="i24"]/div[3]/div', 
           'Prefiero no decirlo': '//*[@id="i27"]/div[3]/div'}


sexo='hombre' 

driver.find_element('xpath', sexo_dict[sexo]).click()

#Choice in Estado civil

driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]').click()

estado_civil_dict={'soltero':'//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]',
                   'casado':'//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]',
                   'divorciado':'//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]',
                   'prefiero no decirlo':'//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[6]',
                   }

estado_civil='casado'
driver.find_element('xpath', estado_civil_dict[estado_civil]).click()

# test line
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]').click()
```

and I have an error in this line, the test one:

```
driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]').click()
```

Error:

`ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.75)`

What is wrong with `Estado civil` part. I click in the box and then I choice an option within the dictionary as in the previous case, but now I cannot enter.

Answer (score 0):

I also didn't manage to select an option by using a click, because it's a select element that consists of divs which behaves weirdly.
I managed to solve it using `ActionChains` and performing a KeyDown and Enter keypress after opening the select.

Here is the code i used to make it work:

```
#Choice in Estado civil
select_elem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]'))).click()
time.sleep(3)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
actions.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
actions.perform()
time.sleep(10)
```